# How to group data from a multiindex column dataframe for split violin- or boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I computed data that I saved into a nested dictionary. Subsequently, I loaded this dictionary into a Pandas DataFrame, called `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): dict_data2[i][j] 
                           for i in dict_data2.keys() 
                           for j in dict_data2[i].keys()},
                       orient='columns')
```

This dataframe is organized and looks as follows when I print it.

```
         rest                      ...      task                    
           V1        V2        V3  ...      VMA1      VMA2      VMA3
0    5.166667  5.833333  5.300000  ...  4.766667  4.800000  4.766667
1    5.166667  5.566667  5.266667  ...  4.766667  4.800000  4.733333
2    5.200000  5.633333  5.300000  ...  4.833333  4.900000  4.733333
3    5.000000  5.600000  5.333333  ...  4.966667  5.033333  4.900000
4    4.966667  5.800000  5.333333  ...  5.000000  5.066667  5.033333
..        ...       ...       ...  ...       ...       ...       ...
724  5.300000  6.233333  6.366667  ...  5.233333  5.666667  5.533333
725  5.266667  6.266667  6.366667  ...  5.333333  5.633333  5.633333
726  5.266667  6.266667  6.400000  ...  5.333333  5.500000  5.466667
727  5.333333  6.266667  6.400000  ...  5.366667  5.500000  5.433333
728  5.566667  6.266667  6.366667  ...  5.400000  5.533333  5.400000

[729 rows x 22 columns]
```

The dataset has two major groups, `rest` and `task`. Both major groups share subgroups, such as `V1`, over `V2`, to `VMA3`. While these subgroups are shared between both `rest` and `task`, the data (729 data points per subgroup) is not identical. That is, `rest V1` does not contain the same values as `task V1`. Hence, all subgroups exist for both `rest` and `task`, but contain different values.

**Aim:** I would like to use `seaborn` to plot violin- or boxplots with the option `split=True` (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html), so that one side of the plot should show the `rest` data, and the other side of the plot should show the `task` data. Hence, each subregion, say `V1` should share one violin- or boxplot, but with the left side showing the `rest` and the right side of the plot showing the `task` data distribution.

**Problem:** I don't understand how one has to format the Pandas DataFrame `df` so that `seaborn` can read the actual data as per my aim. The problem is the "nested" data structure in the dataframe.

**Question:** Is there a way to format `df` to achieve my aim, or would I have to switch to another method of organizing my data not using a Pandas DataFrame?

Here is my current code and what the result looks like. Currently, seaborn still plots rest and task violinplots separately, because I do not understand yet how to re-format my dataframe `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): dict_data2[i][j] 
                           for i in dict_data2.keys() 
                           for j in dict_data2[i].keys()},
                       orient='columns')
     
colors = ["coral", "gold", "mediumseagreen", "blueviolet",
"mediumorchid", "bisque", "cornflowerblue"]

sns.violinplot(data=df, 
               orient="h", width=3, linewidth=1,
               saturation=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with something similar to already posted answer, but it seems a bit more compact. I use pandas `melt`:

```
sns.violinplot(data=pd.melt(df, var_name=["type", "subtype"]), 
               x="value", y="subtype", hue="type", split=True,
               orient="h")
```

Output:[image]

This is based on a mock dataset created from your input example - I used
`rest V1, V2, V3` as is and `task VMA1, VMA2, VMA3` as `task V1, V2, V3`, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

So funnily enough I had to do this yesterday. I admit my solution is not the cleanest but it works.

First you need to change your data frame so that it has the structure that seaborn uses (vals in one column, category in another). To do that you do:

```
## Concatenates different variables
df=pd.concat([data[["rest"]], data[["task"]]]).reset_index(drop=True)
## Creates one column of values
df["value"]=df["rest"].fillna(df["task"])
## Created second column with category name for the corresponding value
df["rest"]=(df["rest"]/df["rest"]).replace(1, "rest")
df["task"]=(df["task"]/df["task"]).replace(1, "task")
df["variable"]=df["rest"].fillna(df["task"])
```

Now with that out of the way its time to plot

```
sns.violinplot(data=df, x=var_in_xaxis, y="value", hue="variable", split=True, ax=ax, inner=None)
```

It wasn't clear to me what variable you are using for the x axis so I left it for you to fill out.

Edit: I guess since your data is a multicolumn dataframe, then you'd need to use groupby to apply this to each one of the subcolumns and then aggregate it and/or plot it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I only accept the other answer as solution because the code is even simpler or shorter. But your code works too when using groupby.